# How do I read an Apache log?

Tags: apache-2.2, logging

I see lines like this in my apache usage log, but don't understand how to read them:

```
123.16.65.84 - - [04/Nov/2011:00:30:09 +0000] "GET /media/product/3596_5084_120.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 175 "http://www.audaaai.com/loa-hi-fi_dm13.html&brand=36" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; GTB7.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; AskTbMPC2/5.11.0.15286)"
```

How can I understand these lines?

Comment: [Google is hard, let's go shopping!](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/logs.html)

Answer (score 6):

- `123.16.65.84` is the IP-address of the client.
- The first hyphen would contain the client-identifier from `identd`, but a hyphen is in its place as that information is unavailable.
- The second hyphen would contain the users `username`, if the user were authenticated by http.
- `[04/Nov/2011:00:30:09 +0000]` is the time of the request.
- `GET` is the request method
- `/media/product/3596_5084_120.jpg` is the request URI
- `HTTP/1.1` is the protocol and version
- `304` is the returned status code. (304 means 'Not Modified')
- `175` is the amount of bytes in the returned body.
- `http://www.audaaai.com/loa-hi-fi_dm13.html&brand=36` is the referer-URL
- `Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; GTB7.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; AskTbMPC2/5.11.0.15286)` is the user agent / browser used by the client.

Check out http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/logs.html#common for a more thorough explanation.